# Dependency of rJava on JDK

Tags: rjava

Why does rJava need the entire JDK installed instead of just the JRE ? (jvm.dll is available in the JRE)

Let us assume that the path to jvm.dll and all other environment variables are set correctly.

Comment: I had the same question trying to fix my java problem. JDK vs JRE was not the problem (JRE seems to be OK). My problem was resolved by using install.packages("SqlRender",INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")

Answer (score 0):

The rJava package does not need JDK. JRE is sufficient for all the functions. Previous errors were related to 64bit JDK only bundling 32bit JRE. And that was the problem.

Comment: if you need rJava for other packages, try: install.packages("SqlRender",INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")